# External filter form with Datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I have a form that I want to send all fields to serverside using Datatables and filter the data.

I found how to send individual parameters using:

```
url: './demo2/contents/orden/get.php',
type: 'POST',
data: function(d) { 
d.comercial = $("#comercial").val(); 
}
```

but how can I send the complete form, I assume it can be done using something similar:

```
url: './demo2/contents/orden/get.php',
type: 'POST',
data: function(d) { 
var frm_data = $('#searchFrom').serializeArray();
$.each(frm_data, function(key, val) { 
d[val.name] = val.value;
}); 
}
```

To get the parameters in get.php I am using

$comercial = $_REQUEST["comercial"];

Comment: Use `$_POST` to get the variables

Comment: I get an error using d[val.name] = val.value; not sure how to define this

Comment: When sending form inputs to a PHP file via `POST` as you've done here, you access them using the `$_POST` variable. So for example, you have a text input named `email` you would access the value in PHP using `$_POST['email']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody needs help with this. I found the solution. You can get the forms post values using the same datatable get file without have to post again.. I wasnt aware of this.

here is the code:

```
$('#kt_search').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var frm_data = $('#searchFrom').serializeArray();


        console.log(frm_data);  

        $.each(frm_data, function(key, val) {

        myData[val.name]    = val.value;

        });

        table.table().draw();


        });
```

If you need to send an array because you have a field with multiple selection, you can use the following. Hope it helps somebody.

```
$('#kt_search').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var frm_data = $('#searchFrom').serializeArray();

        //POST VALUES ARE SENT USING SAME GET FILE NO NEED TO POST AGAIN
        var multiple = {};

        var i = 0;
        $.each(frm_data, function(key, val) {

        var str = val.name; 

        //CHECK IF FIELD NAME FINISHES WITH MULTIPLE
        if (str.match("_multiple")){

        if (typeof multiple[str] == "undefined") {
        multiple[str] = new Array();
        i = 0;
        }

        multiple[str][i] = val.value;        

        i++; 

        myData[val.name] = multiple[str];

        }else{

        myData[val.name]    = val.value;

        }

        });

        table.table().draw();


        });
```